# Connect to KeyVault in Azure China

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk-.net, azure-china

I use this code for Azure KeyVault Service and it works well with a regular Azure

```
ClientSecretCredential clientCredential = new(options.KeyVaultTenantId, options.KeyVaultClientId, options.KeyVaultClientSecret);
KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy rootCertificate = new CertificateClient(vaultUri, _clientCredential).GetCertificate(_rootCertificateId).Value;
```

however I need to connect to Azure China. The code fails with message:

> AADSTS90002: Tenant 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' not found.
> Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID and are signing into the correct cloud.
> Check with your subscription administrator, this may happen if there
> are no active subscriptions for the tenant

I found [this](https://chowdera.com/2021/01/20210120055654842j.html) but I don't know where to set `ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.AzureChina` in my code. Please suggest

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates" Version="4.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys" Version="4.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.2.0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [`ClientSecretCredential(String, String, String, ClientSecretCredentialOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-identity-clientsecretcredential-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-string-azure-identity-clientsecretcredentialoptions)) constructor override and set the [`AuthorityHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.tokencredentialoptions.authorityhost?view=azure-dotnet#azure-identity-tokencredentialoptions-authorityhost) to Azure China in [`ClientSecretCredentialOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredentialoptions?view=azure-dotnet).

Something like:

```
var clientSecretCredentialOptions = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions()
{
    AuthorityHost =  AzureAuthorityHosts.AzureChina
};

ClientSecretCredential clientCredential = new(options.KeyVaultTenantId, options.KeyVaultClientId, options.KeyVaultClientSecret, clientSecretCredentialOptions);
KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy rootCertificate = new CertificateClient(vaultUri, _clientCredential).GetCertificate(_rootCertificateId).Value;
```